# Alexa skill failure using Lambda - The requested skill's response

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

When testing out my skill using the Test Simulator for Alexa I am getting the following error:

> There was a problem with the There was a problem with the requested skill's response

I tried looking at solutions, but I could not find anything.

If anyone can help, I'd very much appreciate it!

Thanks!

This is what is being sent to Lambda

## Code Editor

```js
{
  "languageModel": {
    "intents": [
      {
        "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
        "samples": []
      },
      {
        "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
        "samples": []
      },
      {
        "name": "AMAZON.NoIntent",
        "samples": []
      },
      {
        "name": "AMAZON.RepeatIntent",
        "samples": []
      },
      {
        "name": "AMAZON.StartOverIntent",
        "samples": []
      },
      {
        "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
        "samples": []
      },
      {
        "name": "AMAZON.YesIntent",
        "samples": []
      },
      {
        "name": "AnswerIntent",
        "samples": [
          "the answer is {Answer}",
          "my answer is {Answer}",
          "is it {Answer}",
          "{Answer} is my answer",
          "{Answer}"
        ],
        "slots": [
          {
            "name": "Answer",
            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "DontKnowIntent",
        "samples": [
          "i don't know",
          "don't know",
          "i don't know that one",
          "dunno",
          "skip",
          "i don't know that",
          "who knows",
          "i don't know this question"
        ],
        "slots": []
      }
    ],
    "invocationName": "geo trivia"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you look into your logs on Lambda to see what exactly happened?

Comment: Does this happen at your skill's invocation? Or, does it happen part way through the skill? Have you tried copying the request JSON from the Amazon test suite into your AWS test suite to see what might be going wrong?

Comment: During my skill's invocation

Comment: Can you please post your skill code? Alexa may be trying to handle a request to an intent where there is no handler.  This also happens when there is a runtime error in your code that is not caught with proper error handling.